# python flask with json

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to get user's input and return the details as json.
But I get an error and I can't find why.
Hers is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,jsonify
import json
@app.route('/user_input')
def user_input():
    return render_template('user-input.html')


@app.route('/user_input',methods = ['POST'])
def result():
    NAME = request.form['Book_Name']
    PAGE = request.form['Page']
    TEXT = request.form['Text']
    TOPIC = request.form['Topic']
    pythonDictionary = {'bookName': NAME, 'page': PAGE, 'text': TEXT, 'topic': TOPIC}
    dictionaryToJson = json.dumps(pythonDictionary)
    return jsonify(dictionaryToJson)
```

and my HTML file:

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/result" method = "POST">
         <p>Book Name <input type = "text" name = "Book_Name" /></p>
         <p>Page <input type = "text" name = "Page" /></p>
         <p>Text <input type = "text" name = "Text" /></p>
         <p>Topic <input type ="text" name = "Topic" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

How can I return the values properly?

Comment: Hope my answer helped, please consider marking it as correct if it did. Wish you a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You are dumping the `dict` twice as `jsonify` also does `json.dumps()` (it also sets the correct response headers for you in addition which is why you should use it instead of `json.dumps()`:

```
dictionaryToJson = json.dumps(pythonDictionary)
return jsonify(dictionaryToJson)
```

Do this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,jsonify
import json
@app.route('/user_input')
def user_input():
    return render_template('user-input.html')


@app.route('/user_input',methods = ['POST'])
def result():
    NAME = request.form['Book_Name']
    PAGE = request.form['Page']
    TEXT = request.form['Text']
    TOPIC = request.form['Topic']
    pythonDictionary = {'bookName': NAME, 'page': PAGE, 'text': TEXT, 'topic': TOPIC}
    return jsonify(pythonDictionary )
```

Answer (score 1):

0) Do not use uppercase for vars. Uppercase is always for constants.

1) Use routes with "/" at the end to avoid additional redirects which flask [does](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/):

```
@app.route('/user_input/', methods = ['POST'])
```

2) Use the **same route** and the **same function** to get what you need:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify


def json_response(status_code, data):
    res = jsonify(data)
    res.status_code = status_code
    return res

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/user_input/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def user_input():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('user-input.html')
    else:
        python_dictionary = {'bookName': request.form.get('Book_Name'),
                             'page': request.form.get('Page'),
                             'text': request.form.get('Text'),
                             'topic': request.form.get('Topic')}
        return json_response(200, python_dictionary)

app.run()
```

3) And yes, you don't need to use `json.dumps(pythonDictionary)` before passing dictionary to `jsonify`

4) Consider to use `request.form.get('key')` rather than `request.form['key']` because get() function [returns](https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/5saebt/pset_7_flask_requestform_vs_requestformget/) None if there is no such key:value instead of raising key error exception.

Comment: The only advantage of having a forward slash at the route end ('/user_input/') is that it won't throw an exception if the browser comes without the slash ('/user_input'), but otherwise there is no other advantage of using it, right? (Already read the linked docs).

Comment: There is no exception if a browser comes without the slash. There is just a redirect to route with this slash. From the docs:

Though they look rather similar, they differ in their use of the trailing slash in the URL definition. In the first case, the canonical URL for the projects endpoint has a trailing slash. In that sense, it is similar to a folder on a filesystem. Accessing it without a trailing slash will cause Flask to redirect to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.